# Initialize instance of singleton descendant

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-constructor, object-initialization

In a traditional singleton, you can initialize the instance like so:

```
private static readonly Messages _instance = new Messages();
```

Then you access it via a getter, like so:

```
    public static Messages Instance {
        get {
            return _instance;
        }
    }
```

In this case, we have a parent and multiple descendants.

In the parent we have

```
    protected static Base _instance;
    public static Base Instance {
        get {
            return _instance;
        }
    }
```

In the descendant, we use the class constructor to populate the static variable.

```
    static Derived() {
        _instance = new Derived();
    }
```

This should work because the class constructor is called when the class is first referenced, before it is used.
For some reason, this is not working.

```
   Derived.Instance.Initialize();
```

fails because Instance is null and the breakpoint in the constructor is never hit.

Update: The Base constructor gets called, but the Derived constructor does not.
This may be because the static constructor is triggered when a static method is called on the class. The static method I am calling is on the parent, not the descendant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The static method I am calling is on the parent, not the descendant.

This was the problem. The class constructor of the base was called because a static method belonging to the parent was called.

The descendant class constructor isn't called until a static method is called on the descendant.

```
Derived1.EmptyStaticMethod(); //This provokes the class constructor
Derived2.EmptyStaticMethod();
Derived1.Instance.Initialize(); // This now works.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not executing the `Derived` constructor because even though you write `Derived.Instance`, C# is being clever and realizing that `Instance` is actually defined on `Base` - and re-writes the call to be `Base.Instance.Initialize()`, so it doesn't initialize `Derived`.

Anyway, this seems like a very bad idea. What happens when you create and reference `Derived2` which also sets the instance? Now you've gone and clobbered `Derived.Instance`.

Without knowing *why* you're doing this, the workaround is to define a static member on Derived which is referenced externally before `Derived.Instance`, or create a `new static Derived Instance` on `Derived`.

Here's an example to demonstrate that `Dervied2` will overwrite the instance:

```
void Main()
{
    //Prints null
    Console.WriteLine(Derived.Instance?.Name);

    //Prints Derived
    var a = Derived.InitDerived;
    Console.WriteLine(Derived.Instance?.Name);

    //Prints Derived2
    var b = Derived2.InitDerived;
    Console.WriteLine(Derived.Instance?.Name);
}

public class Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    protected static Base _instance;
    public static Base Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public static int InitDerived = 1;
    static Derived()
    {
        _instance = new Derived() { Name = "Derived" };
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public static int InitDerived = 2;
    static Derived2()
    {
        _instance = new Derived()  { Name = "Derived2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: > What happens when you create and reference Derived2?

Comment: I assumed you were right about instance getting clobbered, but it actually works. Each class creates and holds the correct instance.

Comment: @BWhite Are you sure about that? I've just tested it to double check, and it definitely *does* get overwritten. See my edit

Comment: That's especially interesting given this line

    _instance = new Derived() // in Derived2

Comment: @BWhite Sorry - that was a typo, but changing it to `new Derived2()` has the same effect. We're still setting `Base._instance`

Comment: This has me stumped so far. Yours fails and mine succeeds. Not seeing the difference so far. I thought perhaps it was Name. Got rid of that but using GetType().ToString() gives the same result. instance is overridden by Derived2.

Comment: @BWhite Nothing to do with that. Each static constructor writes to `Base._instance`. They don't create separate objects - they refer to the same thing. Which ever constructor gets called *last* is the one who decides what `_instance` will be

Comment: Looking for the differences revealed my typo. Thanks for the help. Now I need to go back and redesign the architecture.

Comment: @BWhite No worries mate

Comment: Just to wrap this up, the typo was only in my simplified code. In my case, I got lucky. Since I'm using a generic as the base, BaseCollection<T>: List<T>, it doesn't get overwritten. No redesign needed.

Comment: @BWhite Yes - that would fix it, but you'll need to be sure that `Derived` and `Derived2` provide different generic arguments to `BaseCollection<T>`. If they are both, for example, `: BaseCollection<int>`, you'll run into the same issue